# Self-Restarting Script in Python on Windows

Tags: python

I have a script that is communicating with an outside server that sometimes throws out errors and mucks up my program. I have tried to workaround it, but it seems like it keeps throwing errors unless I manually restart the program.

Is there any way on Windows to have a python script restart itself on error? I see this ox.exec whenever I search these types of things and just can't seem to figure out making it work

```
In my main code: 
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    logout()



def logout():
gv.logout()
time.sleep(20)
login()



def login():
try:
    gv.login(settings.user,settings.passw)
    textcheck()
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    time.sleep(30)
    login()
```

Comment: it isn't possible for you to catch the exceptions? Can you post a code snippet (or, better, some error output) that shows what's going on?

Comment: Hey, I am catching them, but it seems to be coming from the server I'm contacting and I just need to restart it. I tried re-connecting to the server but it keeps spitting back the old error until I manually restart the program

Comment: again, you really need to post some specifics for anyone to be able to help you.  Part of the problem may be that you need to sleep your program for a bit when it starts getting errors from the server (maybe slowly increasing the interval or something).

Comment: added! Sorry I am using the sleep, and have tried doing the increasing time/etc.

Comment: If it helps, I'm getting an error from another python script I'm importing, I'm new obviously to Python but is there a way to re-import a script?

Answer (score 1):

you can run another program to check if it is alive, e.g. python program update a heartbeat file every minutes, and your guarder process check if the files last modified time to see the other end is alive. you can also use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),just write a query

```
select * from win32_process where xxx
```

to check if python script is running.

Comment: What do you mean check if it is alive?

Comment: if your script encounter some error can not handle gracefully, such as "memory can not read", "stack overflow", just quit your program, and guarder script can find out it is dead.

Comment: I did a quick search for something like this and am currently coming up nill, any help on a lead to where I could start on something like this?